# C++11 type inference with lambda and std::function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, type-inference

I have the following snippet of code, that although entirely trivial, illustrates a pattern I am trying to use in more general code.

```cpp
template<typename InT, typename ResT>
ResT unary_apply( InT val, std::function<ResT(InT)> fn )
{
    return fn(val);
}
```

I would like to be able to call unary_apply with function pointers, functors, lambdas etc: hence the use of `std::function` to abstract that all away.

When I try to use the above in the following way, C++ (g++ 4.7) is unable to perform the relevant type inference:

```cpp
double blah = unary_apply( 2, []( int v ) { return 3.0 * v; } );
```

Failing with

```cpp
src/fun.cpp:147:75: error: no matching function for call to ‘unary_apply(int, test()::<lambda(int)>)’
src/fun.cpp:147:75: note: candidate is:
src/fun.cpp:137:6: note: template<class InT, class ResT> ResT unary_apply(InT, std::function<ResT(InT)>)
src/fun.cpp:137:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
src/fun.cpp:147:75: note:   ‘test()::<lambda(int)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<ResT(double)>’
```

And I find that I have to explicitly specify the template parameters (in practice I believe it is just the return type that is not inferable):

```cpp
double blah = unary_apply<int, double>( 2, []( int v ) { return 3.0 * v; } );
```

I am not that familiar with the type inference rules in C++11, but the above behaviour does seem reasonable (I can see that inferring via the internal mechanics of `std::function` is probably rather a big ask). My question is: is it possible to re-write the `unary_apply`function above to keep the same flexibility (in terms of the types of functions/functors etc that can be passed as a second parameter) whilst also giving more of a clue to type inference so I do not have to explicitly supply the template parameters at the point of call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Going bit more duck-typey should work:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto unary_apply(T&& val, F&& func) -> decltype(func(val)) {
    return func(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

Comment: The proposed solution is correct, the first sentence is not. The reason why type inference cannot be applied in the question is unrelated to the fact that it is a lambda (you could pass any other functor/function and it would still be unable to infer the type)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Read it again. Lambda is not a *function* type. It's a unnamed class type with `operator()`. But yeah, with `std::function<R(T)>` the inference probably wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I missed that part, corrected the comment: the problem is not that it is a lambda but that the template argument to `std::function` is in an uneducable context, try passing a regular function (not `std::function<>` --or did you mean that *lambda is not a `std::function` instantiation?)

Comment: That does indeed do the trick. Thanks very much. Can you recommend any resources online explaining the difference between the inferencing rules for templates and for decltype?

Comment: @AlexWilson: You can try searching SO, but really the only place you can rely on is the standard itself.

Comment: I guess I can have a look at the draft (which I understand is free). Thanks for the prompt help.

Comment: @AlexWilson: The problem here is not that the inference rules for templates or `decltype` might differ, but how it was being used. Template requires a perfect match of the types (only const-volatile qualifiers are allowed), and in your case the function took a `std::function<?>` but the argument was a lambda. A `std::function<>` can be constructed from different things including a lambda, but they are different types, requiring a conversion that is not allowed in that context. In the case of `decltype` the type `F` is inferred to be that of the lambda.

Comment: ... after the types have properly been inferred (and only after the types are fixed) the compiler will evaluate the `decltype` expression to obtain the trailing return type. There is no type inference in the `decltype` case.

Comment: @dribeas Thanks for the extra detail. Am coming to c++11 with some Scala type inference rules in my head. They've not helping, as C++ rules didn't the other way around...

Comment: @AlexWilson With a background in Scala I recommend you stay away from using `std::function` in function parameters (inference or not). Things like `std::vector<std::function<Sig>>` are good use cases for `std::function`, but things like `void pass_callback(std::function<int()> cb);` have some warts.

Comment: @LucDanton. I've been using boost::function for some time without any particular issues. Do you have any more details on issues with your latter example?

Comment: @AlexWilson Unfortunately I don't know of any resource (on this site or elsewhere) that describes the situation and I don't think a description would fit in the comments.